# How to distinguish left/right/middle click events in all browsers, with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

(I know there are similar questions already, but I can't find one that is non-jQuery and covers all browsers.)

I need a function that takes a JavaScript click event and returns `1` for a left click, `2` for a middle click, and `3` for a right click.

Yes, this is what `event.which` is supposed to be, but not all browsers support it, so you have to use `event.button` ...but then some browsers do the numbering differently for that property. I have found it surprisingly difficult to work out how to do this.

I want something that works in all browsers including IE6+ (please don't question this), Firefox 3.6+, Chrome 10+, Safari 5+.

**No jQuery please.**

Comment: Since jQuery is just Javascript, if there's some jQuery plugin that does that, you could simply look at its source code and take that. It's probably going to boil down to a long list of if-elses that cover all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the link [Mouse events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events) which is providing a nice explanation.
You can use the code provided in there as work around.

```
function fixWhich(e) {
    if (!e.which && e.button) {
        if (e.button & 1) e.which = 1 // Left
        else if (e.button & 4) e.which = 2 // Middle
        else if (e.button & 2) e.which = 3 // Right
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.